# Múltiple WHERE en SQL

Tags: php, sql

Necesito hacer una consulta con múltiples datos en `SQL`, he probado de la siguiente forma pero no lo consigo

```html
 $enero = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM avisos WHERE (fecha BETWEEN '$mes1' AND '$mes0';) AND parametro='5'";
```

Comment: Esta consulta que devuelve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creo que si cambiamos un poco el orden de tus condiciones y quitamos el **;** debería de funcionar. Eso si tienes definidas tus variables **$mes1** y **$mes0** y son dates con un formato válido:

```
$enero = "SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM avisos WHERE parametro='5' AND fecha BETWEEN '$mes1' AND '$mes0'";
```